# Unit testing for D-Bus and HAL?

Tags: python, unit-testing, dbus, hal

How does one test a method that does some interactions with the local D-Bus (accessing a HAL object)?

Results of tests will differ depending on the system that the test is run on, so I don't know how to provide the method reliable input.

I'm working in Python, by the way.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

If you can not mock the environment then it's probably impossible for you to write the test.
If your access to HAL/D-Bus is via an object and you provide a mock instance to your test then it should be possible to emulate the necessary inputs to your test from the mock implementation.

Comment: +1 -> I was about to post the same thing; emulate the interface so that you can load the test inputs/responses that you expect and make sure your software responds as it should.

Answer (score 0):

It's also possible to create a temporary D-Bus buses for tests, and emulate any services your program uses in your test code. You can use this approach for programs which are D-Bus services, D-Bus clients, or both. The downside is that the bus setup is a bit hairy. There's [code for doing this](http://git.collabora.co.uk/?p=telepathy-gabble.git;a=tree;f=tests/twisted/tools) in e.g. Telepathy Gabble.